# How to modify a Jlabel using a different class?

Tags: java, swing, menu, window, jlabel

Hello I wonder how to create a class which modifies an already consisting JLabel ( which is placed in another class). I would like to be able to choose the JLabels color, size and so on and then use this class in the one containing the JLabels.

How i started : http://pastebin.com/xUJJrJZk;

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You either make the JLabel accessible by making it public, or create a getter method to retrieve the private instance of it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example) direct to SO (no 'links').

Answer (score 0):

1. Create one class say ApplicationManager.
2. Create one JLabel jlabel1.
3. create setter and getter method for this JLabel.
4. call the setter method from your original class constructor.

and call getter method where you want.It will return you another reference of your original Jlabel,you can call setText or other method from getter method which will return JLabel.

Comment: My problem is that ( if you check the current code) im not sure how to be able to modify the already existing Jlabels even if i create a get and set method ?